# Why does Grand Solar Minimum occurs?

Tags: astronomy, solar-system

Recently I was reading about the Little Ice age that happened in 13th to 19th century that caused mild summer and bitter winters ( also known as Grand Solar Minimum (GSM ). How did this occured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are conflating two separate concepts. The [Little Ice Age](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Ice_Age) is a period of cooler weather from about 1300 to about 1850. We know from written records that this affected Europe and North America, and there is some evidence from geological records that it may have been a global phenomena, although this is not certain.

A [Grand Solar Minimum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_minimum#Grand_solar_minima_and_maxima) is a period of lower than average sun spot and aurora activity extending over several of the well-established 11 year cycles of solar activity. During the Little Ice Age there were three GSMs - the Sporer minimum, the Maunder minimum and the Dalton minimum. Solar minima (and corresponding solar maxima, such as the Modern maximum from 1950 to 2009) are caused by cycles in the sun's magnetic field - sunspots are manifestations on the surface of the sun of complex magnetic field events occurring deep within the sun. The behaviour of the sun's magnetic field is complex and not completely understood.

Solar minima have been put forward as one possible explanation for the Little Ice Age, but other explanations have also been proposed. One alternative explanation is atmospheric changes due to [increased global volcanic activity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Ice_Age_volcanism).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty So it is :) Fixed.